# prime numbers in an interval, binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, prime-numbers

I have two combinatoric questions:

1. Let $p(n)$ denote the number of unordered sets of positive integers whose sum is $n$. I proved that:
   $$p(n) \geq \max_{1\leq k\leq n}\left\{\frac{1}{k!}{n-1 \choose k-1} \right\}.$$
   I need to use it to show that there is an absolute constant $c > 0$ for which:
   $$p(n) \geq e^{c\sqrt{n}}$$
   I don't know about any lower bound that involves $e$ and I'm really stuck.
2. Let $\pi(m, n)$ denote the set of prime numbers in the interval $[m,n]$.
   I showed that the product of all the prime numbers between $1$ to $n$ less than or equal to $4^n$.
   I need to show that $|\pi(1, n)|$ = $O(n/\log n)$. 
   I thought of maybe showing it by induction, dividing the interval of $(1,n)$ to $(1,\sqrt{n})$ and$(\sqrt n,n)$ but it did'nt work.

I know this is a lot but I can really use some help.
Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for starters, for what value of $k$ is $f(n,k)=\frac1{k!}\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ maximized? Consider the ratio
$$
\frac{p(n,k+1)}{p(n,k)}=\frac{n-k}{k(k+1)}
$$
This ratio starts above one when $k$ is small, and ends below one when $k$ is close to $n$. The time when the ratio goes from above one to below one is where $p(n,k)$ is maximized. We can  see this occurs at about $k\approx -1+\sqrt[]{n+1}$, suggesting that plugging in $\sqrt{n}$ for $k$ into that inequality should give the best bound on $p(n)$. In other words, you should use 
$$
p(n)\ge \frac1{(\sqrt{n})!}\binom{n-1}{\sqrt n-1}
$$
and show the right hand side to be grows faster than $e^{c\sqrt{n}}$. To do this, use Stirling's approximation.

---

The product of $\pi(n)$ distinct numbers positive integers is at least $\pi(n)$!. Since you know the product of the $\pi(n)$ primes in $[1,n]$ is at most $4^n$, this tells you
$$
\pi(n)!\le 4^n
$$
If $\pi(n)$ was not $O(n/\log n)$, then it follow that $\pi(n)=C(n)n/\log n$, where $C(n)$ is some function which is not bounded, meaning $C(n)$ can be made arbitrarily large by plugging in an appropriate $n$. So show that
$$
(C(n)n/\log n)!\le 4^n
$$
leads to a contradiction for such a function $C(n)$. Again, Stirling's approximation is indispensable.